# ASM: Optimization of Pass-by-value vs Pass-by-reference in leading-edge compilers?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, clang, x86-64

(This question is about compiler optimization assembly, not about the use of pointers in code.)

I'm trying to determine if I can take advantage of optimizations built into Clang or GCC in regards to whether the variable is passed by value or reference.

For some background I'm working on a "my own language" to C++ transliterator that does some level of preprocessing to the code. It occurred to me that it should be possible to determine at compile time whether a variable is more efficiently passed around by reference or by value. It would mean writing different versions of functions automatically, etc. but that is all doable.

I suspected that the compilers do this already to some extent. The question is: to what extent?

I've noticed by playing with Godbolt's Compiler Explorer that on higher optimization levels the resulting ASM is nothing like the code. I'm beginning to realize that many best practices and optimizations that are typically done in code no longer matter because the compilers are so damn efficient. Does this expand to pass-by-reference vs. pass-by-value?

And the big question: What if I just made everything pass-by-value with no thought for memory-efficiency or copy speed, and just let the compiler decide... would it correctly optimize?

If so I could design my language so the coder only needs to consider whether a write is done to the parent variable or results in a copy, and the whole world of reference and pointers can be delegated to the compiler. It's a completely different way of thinking.

My initial testing on Compiler Explorer with Clang (widberg) shows a difference in the ASM begins at optimization level `-O2` (same ASM before that). You can see the code and ASM here:

[Small Struct on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Kj6zEeE6q)

[Larger Struct on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vzTcz97rc)

I've been trying to work it out, but I don't know enough assembly to figure out if I've found what I'm looking for.

Is it passing by value in the small struct version and by reference in the larger version?

Comment: Quite interestingly, this is one of the major goals of [Carbon](https://github.com/carbon-language/carbon-lang/blob/trunk/README.md) the language that Google is promoting to replace C++. Check [this article](https://www.foonathan.net/2022/07/carbon-calling-convention/).

Comment: Global (non-`static`) functions need to follow the standard calling convention, for inter-operability with any compiler (version/optimization options), except when they inline.  In theory GCC or clang could make a clone of it with a special symbol name that uses a custom calling convention, but I haven't seen that.

Comment: Making *everything* pass-by-value sounds like a bad idea. Labview does it for most of its stuff and it severely limits you in your coding patterns until you start abusing features like multi-producer-consumer queues with single entries as sort-of-pointers. Matlab also uses pass-by-value (with copy-on-write) but at least has handle types for pass-by-reference

Comment: Both structs are passed by value and returned by ref, that's what you asked for in C++. The difference is due to unrolling the initialization. Passing small values by value may improve the performance a bit but the value [must be small, <16/32 bytes top (ideally 8 bytes)](https://godbolt.org/z/jjrThxEah). Duplicating a function may incur other penalties (like icache misses). I strongly advice you to read the SYS V ABI as all of this has already been solved.

Comment: How different is your language? In Ada we have `in` and `in out` parameters, and the compiler decides how to pass those. In C++ however, copy vs reference is visible if a function can access the parameter in a different way, like a global variable or a second parameter - if inside `f(x,y)` the code assigns to x, does y change? (Ada bans assigning to in-parameters...).